# Use ViewControllers in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to use a UIScrollView and a UIPageController to display my View controllers instead of using a navigation controller. How would I go about this? Is it possible to load a view controller inside of a UIScrollView or is there a different way? I doesn't need to have a UISCrollView I just want to be able to scroll between my View Controllers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using storyboards and ios6+ you can place multiple "container views" within the scroll view. Then embed your individual view controllers to them. Clean and no code required for layout.

Comment: No idea how to use story board. Never really got the point or advantage sorry.

Comment: Well, the point and advantage of storyboard is letting you doing exactly what you want to do in this case, without writing a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

UIViewController is not a UIView descendant. You can add views of your viewControllers to UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Nope scrollview cannot handle UIViewcontroller.Just get the view from your VCs and add as subview in scrollview